# Simple method to generate posts from files

Tags: posts

I have an application that runs locally on my computer. It parses a large database of many gigabytes and generates several dozen HTML files. I would like to publish these files on a WordPress site. How can this be done in a simple way, without creating a few dozen posts by hand?

My application outputs text files. Now it outputs files formatted as HTML. Actually, these files can be in any format, not necessarily HTML, for example, Markdown or some other. I need to upload them to the site and create posts or articles from them.

Comment: Do you have the option to use WP CLI? You will need to perform conversion to HTML before the content is added to WordPress, as they must be HTML. Also, you cannot ask for plugin recommendations here, for that go to the software recommendations stack, this is a programming stack and any answer you get will require basic developer knowledge to understand

Answer (score -1):

One way is to have the posts in a Json format, and use wp_insert_post(); to automatically create the posts.

documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: How would you call wp_insert_post here, and how would you get the JSON data to it? You'd probably do better posting JSON formatted posts to the REST API instead: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post